# Compiling Tensorflow and Bazel on 32-bit Linux

Tags: python, compilation, debian, 32-bit

I was trying to compile bazel on my Debian 32-bit.
I started the process with this command:

```
env EXTRA_BAZEL_ARGS="--host_javabase=@local_jdk//:jdk" BAZEL_JAVAC_OPTS="-J-Xms384m -J-Xmx512m" bash ./compile.sh
```

And I get this error:

```
    In file included from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/message.h:122,
                 from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h:29,
                 from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:52:
external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.h:1283:26: note: 'class google::protobuf::FileDescriptor' declared here
 class LIBPROTOBUF_EXPORT FileDescriptor {
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    At global scope:
    cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-writable-strings'
    ERROR: /path/to/bazel/third_party/BUILD:535:1: Executing genrule //third_party:filter_netty_dynamic_libs failed (Exit 12)

    zip error: Nothing to do! (bazel-out/piii-opt/bin/third_party/netty_tcnative/netty-tcnative-filtered.jar)
    Target //src:bazel_nojdk failed to build
    INFO: Elapsed time: 1173,794s, Critical Path: 37,45s
    INFO: 976 processes: 976 local.
    FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully

    ERROR: Could not build Bazel
```

I searched for a while... but nothing...
Any idea?

I followed the official instructions available at https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-compile-source.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Bazel [does not support 32-bit builds](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1340#issuecomment-373417086). Based on the complexity of builds that Bazel is designed to handle, a 32-bit system is just not feasible to use.